# NXT like standard C?

Tags: nxt, nxc

I'm currently working on a project, where we want to program a swarm of nxts. I have a question to this one, and I can't find a precise answer on the web. So there will be a program on my pc, let's call it a switch, which should connect to 3 robots.

The program on the pc is not an issue, I thought of a simple berkeley socket with AF_BLUETOOTH. Now here the question: Can I write a simple C program for the robot (NXT) as well, or can I use only NXC with it's libraries? What I mean is - can I write a C program with p.ex. #include  and it will work there?

Because all I can find are codes written using only functions the nxc has, and I'd like to write my own socket/connect/accept/and-so-on functions. Is it possible?

Thx :)

Comment: Have you had a look at [Robot C](http://www.robotc.net/)? It's a bit closer to regular C than NXC, and might be able to do what you want.